# Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View

Tags: cocoa, swiftui, macos-sonoma, nsviewrepresentable

There are other answers on SO about this issue but none seen to solve the problem because in my case I am using a `NSViewRepresentable` cocoa view, that is not exactly a SwiftUI view.

I have this code:

```
struct MyObject: Hashable, Identifiable {
  let id: UUID = UUID()
  var name, brand: String
  init(name: String = "", brand: String = "") {
    self.name = varName
    self.brand = brand
  }
}

final class Model:ObservableObject {
  @Published var objects = (0..<3).compactMap {_ in
    return MyObject()
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  
  private let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
  @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      LazyVGrid(
        columns: columns,
        alignment: .center,
        spacing: 10,
        pinnedViews: []
      ) {
        ForEach($model.objects, id:\.id) {$object in
          MyTextField($initObject)
        }
      }
      
    }
    .padding(20)
  }
}

struct MyTextField: View {
  @Binding private var initObject:InitObject
  
  init(_ initObject:Binding<InitObject>) {
    _initObject = initObject
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    AppKitTextField(property: $initObject.name,
                    placeholder: "name",
                    fontName:"Avenir-Medium",
                    fontSize:18) { text in
    }
    
    MyAppKitTextField(property: $initObject.type,
                    placeholder: "type",
                    fontName:"Avenir-Medium",
                    fontSize:18)
      
    }
  }
```

The problem is that `MyAppKitTextField`  is a `AppKit NSTextField` `NSViewRepresentable`, like this:

```
public struct AppKitTextField: NSViewRepresentable {
  public typealias NSViewType = NSTextField
  @Binding var property: String

  public init(property: Binding<String>) {
    self._property = property
  }
    
  public class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextFieldDelegate {
    @Binding private var text: String
    
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
      self._text = text
    }
  }

    public func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<AppKitTextField>) -> NSTextField {
        let textField = NSTextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.stringValue = property
        return textField
      }
      
      public func makeCoordinator() -> AppKitTextField.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $property)
      }
      
      public func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context: Context) {
        nsView.stringValue = property
      }
    }
}
```

My problem is the line

```
@Binding var property: String
```

When I try to use this view I see this error:

```
Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.
```

Comment: Can you please include a [mre] that we can run? What you have has mismatched names/types and can't actually be run by others without modifications

Comment: Binding Should not be in the Coordinator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is `@Binding` property wrapper shouldn't be used in the `Coordinator` class since it's not a `View` where `@Binding` is designed to be used. Instead, you can either use `Binding<String>` or just a closure since you only need to set anyway.

My second guess is this mistake:

```
public func makeCoordinator() -> AppKitTextField.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(text: $property)
}
```

It should be:

```
public func makeCoordinator() -> AppKitTextField.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator() // make is only called once so there is no point in giving it an old version of the binding.
}

public func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context: Context) {

    context.coordinator.textDidChange = nil // just to prevent endless updates depending on how your coordinator is designed

    nsView.stringValue = property

    // must also use the new version of the binding
    context.coordinator.textDidChange = { text
        self.property = text
    }
}
```

FYI Binding is just a pair of get/set closures, there is no need to give the Binding to the Coordinator because it doesn't need the get, thats the reason for the set only `textDidChange` closure which you should invoke from your delegate or action handler.

Comment: but the problem is this. The contents of every element in the `objects` array will be placed inside textfields. Any change to the textfields should be stored back into these elements. How do I do that without binding?

Comment: did you try my code?

Comment: I am trying it now.

Comment: ok and you can still use `Binding<String>` or a closure, just not `@Binding` which is for a `View` that needs `body` to be called on changes.

Comment: ok. I am trying to digest that and make it work with my original code. This posted here is a simplification but I think you are on the right path. I may take a while to do that.

Comment: BRILLIANT. You were right. It is working fine now. I decided to pass a closure. thanks!